# Passing Image URI from one activity to other activity to show selected image from gallery in imageview of second activity

Tags: android, image, android-intent

My `MainActivity.java` file contains following from where my app starts after going through share via button from a image in gallery.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BoardView.class);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.putExtra("image", path);
startActivity(intent);
```

My Second Activity named `BoardView` accepts the image as :

```
Intent ii = getIntent();
Bundle b = ii.getExtras();
if(b!= null) {
    String image = ii.getStringExtra("image");
    view_news.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

But I am not getting my image in second activity.
Actually the first activity is Login and second activity shows the image after login.

EDIT :
Logcat shows error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chawlaz.cubetboard/com.example.chawlaz.cubetboard.BoardView}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
        at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:467)
        at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:457)
        at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:429)
        at com.example.chawlaz.cubetboard.BoardView.onCreate(BoardView.java:156)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)


    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
                    at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                    

    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you mean image is null?

Comment: I mean Image is not getting viewed into my imageview

Comment: From your error log,we can see the image you get is null

Comment: Yeah ,thats what I am asking @FireSun

Comment: ,if so,i think you'd better explain your problem more clearly.

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627575/how-can-i-set-my-selected-image-from-gallery-to-my-application-in-imageview-via) I asked this earlier also and I found my answer,but now I want to integrate login gateway onto this ,due to which I am getting problem.

Comment: @FireSun go through the link please.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ImageView.setImageURI` to show image using `Uri` in ImageView :

```
String image = ii.getStringExtra("image");
view_news.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Uri imgUri=Uri.parse(image);// << get URI from String
view_news.setImageURI(imgUri);
```

Comment: @chawla.19: have you tried as `String image =b.getString("image")` ?

Comment: sir please go through the issue,i can post my code if you want .

Answer (score 0):

declare global static variable

```
public static final String IMAGE_URL = "imageURL";

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BoardView.class);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(IMAGE_URL, path);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in Another Class

```
Intent ii = getIntent();
Bundle b = ii.getExtras();
if(b!= null) {
    String image = ii.getParcelableExtra(MainActivity.IMAGE_URL);
    view_news.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Hope this will help you out

Comment: Your code just change the key of extra to static ,there is nothing helpful to solve this problem.

Comment: Its running but the image is not displaying in Imageview.

Comment: @Muralikrishna I don't think static would be helpful.